# How assign a CStatic derivated to an existing Picture Control in a dialog

Tags: visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and have a picture control inside a dialog box. To drag and drop a file into the picture control I have to create a derevated CStatic class for the picture control.
I have created the new class CDragDrop with the class assistant, but it gave me no possibility to assign the picture control ID to the new class like I can do it for derivated dialog classes.

How I can assign the derivated CStatic class to the picture control inside the dialog window?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any solution to do it directly. But what works, is to destroy the original window and create a new window with the CStatic class CDragDrop.

h file:

```
CDragDrop* m_DragDrop
```

cpp file inside OnInitDialog():

```
CRect rectStatic;
CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_ID3_PICTURE);
pWnd->GetWindowRect(rectStatic);

pWnd->DestroyWindow();

ScreenToClient(rectStatic);

m_DragDrop.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BLACKRECT,
    rectStatic, this, IDC_ID3_PICTURE);

m_DragDrop.ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES);
```